# how can i store objects from object which is itself stored in object (e.g below) in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JavaScript.
I want to create a new array from nested objects.
I have tried to illustrate the structure of my problem.
I want to take objects from children of each object of an array into an new array.
Provided:

```
   [
  {id: 10939, reference_id: 1, name: "A", value: "A", children: {
    1002: {id: 22, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
    1013: {id: 23, reference_id: 23, name: "A2", value: "A2"}
  }},
  {id: 10940, reference_id: 2, name: "B", value: "B", children: {
    1014: {id: 33, reference_id: 33, name: "B1", value: "B1"}
  }},
  {id: 10941, reference_id: 3, name: "C", value: "C", children: {
    IN01: {id: 44, reference_id: 44, name: "C1", value: "C1"},
    IN02: {id: 41, reference_id: 42, name: "C2", value: "C2"},
    IN03: {id: 55, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
    IN04: {id: 55, reference_id: 55, name: "G2", value: "G2"}
  }}
];
```

Expected:

```
[{id: 22, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
 {id: 23, reference_id: 23, name: "A2", value: "A2"},
 {id: 33, reference_id: 33, name: "B1", value: "B1"},
 {id: 44, reference_id: 44, name: "C1", value: "C1"},
 {id: 41, reference_id: 42, name: "C2", value: "C2"},
 {id: 55, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
 {id: 55, reference_id: 55, name: "G2", value: "G2"}
]
```

How can do it?

Comment: You can use Array.reduce. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Please confirm if `children` is an array of objects or an object of objects. I think it's meant to be an array of objects right?

Comment: @its_tayo  children: {1002: {…}, 1013: {…}, 1014: {…}, 1017: {…}, 1018: {…}, 1019: {…}, IN01: {…}, IN02: {…}, IN03: {…}, IN04: {…}, IN05: {…}, …}

Comment: Please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

[`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) will iterate over your Array, and form a new Array with the return value of the function, flattening the final Array

Use [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to select only the `children` entries, and then [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to return only the values of those entries

```js
const data = [
  {id: 10939, reference_id: 1, name: "A", value: "A", children: {
    1002: {id: 22, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
    1013: {id: 23, reference_id: 23, name: "A2", value: "A2"}
  }},
  {id: 10940, reference_id: 2, name: "B", value: "B", children: {
    1014: {id: 33, reference_id: 33, name: "B1", value: "B1"}
  }},
  {id: 10941, reference_id: 3, name: "C", value: "C", children: {
    IN01: {id: 44, reference_id: 44, name: "C1", value: "C1"},
    IN02: {id: 41, reference_id: 42, name: "C2", value: "C2"},
    IN03: {id: 55, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
    IN04: {id: 55, reference_id: 55, name: "G2", value: "G2"}
  }}
];

const resultFlat = data.flatMap(({children}) => Object.values(children));

console.log(resultFlat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: children: {1002: {…}, 1013: {…}, 1014: {…}, 1017: {…}, 1018: {…}, 1019: {…}, IN01: {…}, IN02: {…}, IN03: {…}, IN04: {…}, IN05: {…}, …}

Comment: Can you edit this into your question please, it's rather important

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
let data = [
  {id: 10939, reference_id: 1, name: "A", value: "A", children: {
    1002: {id: 22, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
    1013: {id: 23, reference_id: 23, name: "A2", value: "A2"}
  }},
  {id: 10940, reference_id: 2, name: "B", value: "B", children: {
    1014: {id: 33, reference_id: 33, name: "B1", value: "B1"}
  }},
  {id: 10941, reference_id: 3, name: "C", value: "C", children: {
    IN01: {id: 44, reference_id: 44, name: "C1", value: "C1"},
    IN02: {id: 41, reference_id: 42, name: "C2", value: "C2"},
    IN03: {id: 55, reference_id: 22, name: "A!", value: "A1"},
    IN04: {id: 55, reference_id: 55, name: "G2", value: "G2"}
  }}
];
let result=[];
data.reduce((_,b)=>{
for(key in b.children){ result.push(b.children[key])}});
console.log(result);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question has been updated, if you would like to update your answer with the new data

Comment: @Shiny thanks for mentioning the update in question. I have updated the answer for the same.